# Is it acceptable to unlock premium content in iOS app for users who download within a trial period, share the app, or redeem a custom code?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

We are considering incentivizing users to download our iOS app by offering premium content (informational text) to those who download within a trial period, share the app, or redeem a custom code. However, in order to comply with the App Store Review Guidelines,

```
11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with
mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to
purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected
```

it appears all content unlocking should proceed via the App Store, and especially the In-App Purchase API if any cash changes hands. My questions are:

1. Is it acceptable unlock premium content for users who meet our (non-monetary) qualifications while displaying a paid In-App Purchase option for everyone else?
2. Are there any app developers who have dealt with this issue in the App Store Review Guidelines?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this is a borderline issue. your users aren't purchasing. games also need to be levelled up to gain access to higher levels (which is a form of functionality). so, it's very much about how you present this to the user as to wether it will be rejected. (it's also down to the person who reviews it...). p.s. a free in-app purchase is not possible

Comment: Thanks, Wain! Appreciate your answer. I'll adjust my question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Where would you suggest it goes then @trojanfoe ?

Comment: The Apple Developer Forums.